# Не работает якорь, помогите

Tags: html5

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="menu-toggle"><span></span></div>
</div>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="logo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
          <li><a href="donate.php">Донат</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <a href="#login">
          <div class="nav__ucpbtn">Личный кабинет</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<aside role="slider" id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="slideabout">
              <h1>PORTLAND</h1>
              <p>Предлагаем вам окунуться в захватывающий интересом и возможностями мир ролевой игры в GTA San Andreas по сети. Воплощая свои самые смелые идеи и мечты, вы не сможете остановиться перед открывающимися возможностями.</p>
              <a class="nav__regbtn" href="#register">
                <div class="start">Начать играть</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="slideabout">
              <h1>PORTLAND #2</h1>
              <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Маленький возвращайся, обеспечивает семь над большого свой которое переулка составитель оксмокс агенство жизни снова мир предупреждал ему заголовок, точках
                взгляд.</p>
              <a class="nav__regbtn" href="#register">
                <div class="start">Начать играть</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>

<main id="news">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Новости</h2>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="post">
          <h3>Система промокодов</h3>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Языкового на берегу безорфографичный его до даже использовало продолжил составитель продолжил все дал ручеек большого речью реторический наш сих рыбными, вопроса.</p>
          <div class="post-footer">
            <div class="date">
              22 октября 2017, 13:55
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="next">Подробнее</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="post">
          <h3>Система промокодов</h3>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Языкового на берегу безорфографичный его до даже использовало продолжил составитель продолжил все дал ручеек большого речью реторический наш сих рыбными, вопроса.</p>
          <div class="post-footer">
            <div class="date">
              22 октября 2017, 13:55
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="next">Подробнее</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="post">
          <h3>Система промокодов</h3>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Языкового на берегу безорфографичный его до даже использовало продолжил составитель продолжил все дал ручеек большого речью реторический наш сих рыбными, вопроса.</p>
          <div class="post-footer">
            <div class="date">
              22 октября 2017, 13:55
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="next">Подробнее</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="post">
          <h3>Система промокодов</h3>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Языкового на берегу безорфографичный его до даже использовало продолжил составитель продолжил все дал ручеек большого речью реторический наш сих рыбными, вопроса.</p>
          <div class="post-footer">
            <div class="date">
              22 октября 2017, 13:55
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="next">Подробнее</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<section id="vk">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Мы ВКонтакте</h2>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="social">
          <h3>Присоединяйтесь к нам!</h3>
          <p>нас уже
            <?=$response['members_count']?> человек</p>
          <img src="images/socialpeap.png" alt="Мы ВКонтакте">
          <!-- <a href="https://vk.com/public<?=CONFIG['VK']['group_id']?>" target="_blank"> -->
          <div class="vk__socbtn">Вступить в группу</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
        <div class="ftlogo"></div>
        <p>© 2018 PORTLAND – Мультиплеер GTA San Andreas в режиме RolePlay</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="vctrmyrov"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<!-- REGISTRATION -->

<div class="modal" id="register">
  <a name="register"></a>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <a class="close-modal" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <form action="/register.php" method="POST">
      <div class="nick">
        <input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="Ваш ник">
      </div>
      <div class="mail">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Почта">
      </div>
      <div class="pass">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ваш пароль">
      </div>
      <div class="pass">
        <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Повторите пароль">
      </div>
      <div class="yea">
        <input type="text" name="invitenick" placeholder="Ник пригласившего">
      </div>
      <div class="select">
        <select name="sex">
          <option value="0">Мужской</option>
          <option value="1">Женский</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?=CONFIG['RECAPTCHA']['client-key']?>"></div>
      <div class="signin">
        <input type="submit" value="Продолжить">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Login -->
<div class="modal" id="login">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Авторизация</h2>
    <a class="close-modal" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <div class="nick">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваш ник">
      </div>
      <div class="pass">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ваш пароль">
      </div>
      <div class="signin">
        <input type="submit" value="Войти в аккаунт">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не работает якорь Register на блок Регистрации(Блок регистрации показан коментарием  внизу) ссылка с кнопки `<a class="nav__regbtn" href="#register">`

Answer (score 0):

В HTML5 вместо атрибута `name` при определении якоря нужно использовать атрибут `id`. То есть вот это: `<a name="register"></a>` надо заменить на `<a id="register"></a>`. При этом следует убедиться, что на странице нет других элементов с таким же значением атрибута `id`, поскольку `id` должен быть уникален. Иначе следует придумать якорю другое название.

Comment: <a name="register"></a> исправил на <a id="register"></a> ничего не произошло

Comment: Так же у меня в Блоке регистрации <div class="modal" id="register"> уже прописан якорь, но он не работает

Comment: @МаксимХалин а у Вас точно один атрибут id со значением register? Нельзя иметь 2 id с одинаковым значением на странице.

Comment: @МаксимХалин в общем, дайте Вашей ссылке a и блоку div разные id.

Comment: Дал разные у блока register1 у ссылки register и всё равно ничего не работает

Comment: @МаксимХалин а Вы как проверяете? Я сохранил код в файл и открываю его в браузере. Всё работает. ОС Windows 10, браузер Google Chrome.

Comment: @МаксимХалин хотя у меня и с атрибутом name работает, хотя не должно в HTML5. Браузер похоже просто сам выбирает какой стандарт использовать.

Comment: @МаксимХалин а вообще я вижу такие варианты - 1) На самом деле у Вас всё работает, просто якорь и ссылка на него умещаются в один экран. Тогда браузер не будет скроллить текст. Чтобы проверить это, вставьте между ссылкой и якорем очень большой блок текста.

Comment: @МаксимХалин 2) Ваш HTML-код дополнительно обрабатывается какими-то скриптами, которые меняют его поведение. Это уже не совсем про HTML вопрос, и это я уже не проверю. Я вижу, что Вы используете php  для подстановки значений с сервера, а также подключаете jQuery и Bootstrap, но мне непонятно, может ли что-то из этого менять поведение якорей и гиперссылок.